# Linux Low Level Mouse Reading

Tags: c++, linux, mouse

I want to read mouse position and button state in Linux with C++, but without X or some (high-level) library etc. The only two possibilities I found are reading from the device /dev/input/mice (with fopen,...) or using libgpm. Are there other low level methods?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux all mouse events go through `/dev/input/mouseX`. `/dev/input/mice` is an accumulator in the single mouse devices. Both gpm and X fetch mouse events from `/dev/input/mouseX` or `/dev/input/mice` and forward it.

So reading from `/dev/input/mouseX` or `/dev/input/mice` is as low level as you can get – unless you're using libusb/libhid to directly access a USB mouse device. However accessing a mouse that way will detach it from the kernel, cause just a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks so far. Then is there a "stream-less" way to access the device, ie without fopen etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "stream-less"? You realize that your input devices are sending a stream of input events? What do you mean by "without fopen"? You realize, that Linux, being inspired by Unix abstracts everything into _files_ and processes and that everything is accessed that way?